# Difficulty with two segment uri

Tags: codeigniter, uri

They are trying to create the url, where the first segment is the User and the second is his file, ex: www.exemplo.com/joao/ball

Controller

```
public function user() {

   $user_url = $this->uri->segment(1);

}
```

^^ This would return the profile with every file: www.exemplo.com/joao

```
public function arquivo() {

   $arquivo_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

}
```

^^ This specific file: www.exemplo.com/joao/bola

Routes

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/user/$1';
$route['??'] = 'home/arquivo/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you should use route like this..

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/arquivo';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/user';
```

but as far you with your project this type of routing will give your some hard time. i suggest you to use explicit route name because `(:any)` refer any thing can be pass through this url.

Comment: thanks for me help, but solution for my problem was 

$route['([^/]+)'] = 'home/viewprofile/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/viewalbum/$1';

Answer (score 0):

You can use [routes](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to map the URI and its parameters to the relevant function. CodeIgniter routes behave differently depending on the version of CI.

In CodeIgniter 2.2.0 `(:any)` is [equivalent to the regex, `.+`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.0/system/core/Router.php#L378) - matches one or more of any character (excluding line breaks); in 3.0 and the current development version it is [equivalent to `[^/]+`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/release/3.0/system/core/Router.php#L394) - one or more of any character, excluding line breaks.

The latter is more useful in this case, as you want to identify the two parameters (separated by a forward slash).

In 2.2.0:

```
$route['([^/]+)/([^/]+)'] = 'home/arquivo/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/user/$1';
```

In 3.0:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/arquivo/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/user/$1';
```

---

Controller functions will usually pass the URI parameters as function parameters like this:

```
public function user($user)
{
    // Show the user's profile
}

public function arquivo($user, $file)
{
    // Show the file for the user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve with the following code.

```
$route['([^/]+)'] = 'home/user/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/arquivo/$1';
```